# Different colors plotting fixed points in NSolve

Tags: math, graph, wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I am plotting fixed points of a system of differential equations in terms of a parameter. The code is

```
PX1Y1 = (1 - s1) (y1 + y2);
PX1Y2 = 0;
PX1X2 = 0;
PX2Y1 = 0;
PX2Y2 = s2 (y1 + y2);
PX2X1 = 0;
PY1X1 = s1 (x1 + x2);
PY1Y2 = 0;
PY1X2 = 0;
PY2X1 = 0;
PY2X2 = (1 - s2) (x1 + x2);
PY2Y1 = 0;


x1eq = -x1 (PX1Y1 + PX1Y2 + PX1X2) + x2 PX2X1 + y1 PY1X1 + y2 PY2X1;
x2eq = -x2 (PX2Y1 + PX2Y2 + PX2X1) + x1 PX1X2 + y1 PY1X2 + y2 PY2X2;
y1eq = -y1 (PY1X1 + PY1Y2 + PY1X2) + x1 PX1Y1 + x2 PX2Y1 + y2 PY2Y1;
y2eq = -y2 (PY2X1 + PY2X2 + PY2Y1) + x1 PX1Y2 + x2 PX2Y2 + y1 PY1Y2;

Xsimp[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] = Simplify[x1eq + x2eq]

Xeq = Simplify[
  Xsimp[X/2 + \[Omega]/2, 
   X/2 - \[Omega]/2, (1 - X)/2 - (\[Omega] - \[Gamma])/2, (1 - X)/
     2 + (\[Omega] - \[Gamma])/2]]

\[Omega]simp[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] = Simplify[x1eq - x2eq];

\[Omega]eq = 
 Simplify[\[Omega]simp[X/2 + \[Omega]/2, 
   X/2 - \[Omega]/2, (1 - X)/2 - (\[Omega] - \[Gamma])/2, (1 - X)/
     2 + (\[Omega] - \[Gamma])/2]]

Manipulate[
    Row[{
        paramsplot = {s1 -> a, s2 -> b};
        sol = NSolve[
            {Xeq == 0, \[Omega]eq == 0} /. paramsplot,
            {X, \[Omega]}, Reals
        ];
        Plot[
            X /. sol, {\[Gamma], -1, 1}, 
            AxesLabel -> {"\[Gamma]", "X fixed points"},
            ImageSize-> 300, 
            PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}}
        ],
        Plot[
            \[Omega] /. sol, {\[Gamma], -1, 1}, 
            AxesLabel -> {"\[Gamma]", "\[Omega] fixed points"}, 
            ImageSize -> 300,
            PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
    }], 
    {{a, 0.6,"s1 (0, 1)"}, 0, 1},
    {{b, 0.4, "s2 (0, 1)"}, 0, 1}
]
```

And I get this

[image: Result of executing the code in Mathematica]

Is there any way of plotting each fixed point in a different colour? In the sense that what is green, so to say, in the X graph corresponds to what is green in the omega graph, and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide values for `Xeq` and `\[Omega]eq`?

Comment: As mentioned above, please provide a complete working example.

Comment: Why do you state "Differential Equation" I see only `NSolve[]` no `DSolve[]` or `NDSolve[]`

Comment: I am looking for the fixed points of a set of differential equations, so I use NSolve to numerically compute the points at which the differential equations are 0. The purpose is not to solve the differential equation but to see where the variation is null. @mikuszefski

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Already did it. @ChrisDegnen

Comment: Hi, I was asking for the Tag `differential-equation`. So this is misleading here, right?